# How to define unknown parameter

Tags: calculus

Suppose that I have the following equation and I want to isolate the variable $x_{11}$ on one side and the rest of the equation on the other side:

$$b= a_{1}  x_{1} + a_{2}  x_{2} + \sqrt  { (a_{1}x_{11}+ a_{2} x_{22})^2  }$$ I tried as follows: $$ b - a_{1}  x_{1} - a_{2}  x_{2} =  \sqrt {( (a_{1}x_{11}+ a_{2} x_{22})^2 )  } $$ and then squared both side to eliminate the square root: $$(b - a_{1}  x_{1} - a_{2} x_{2} ) ^ 2 = (a_{1}x_{11}+ a_{2} x_{22})^2.$$ Then we expanded the squared brackets of the RHS:

$$(b - a_{1}  x_{1} - a_{2}  x_{2} ) ^ 2 = (a_{1}x_{11}) ^2 + 2(a_{1}x_{11}) (a_{2} x_{22}) + (a_{2} x_{22})^2$$ and I tried to isolate $x_{11}$ on the RHS from the rest to have $$(b - a_{1}  x_{1} - a_{2}  x_{2} ) ^ 2  - (a_{2} x_{22})^2   =  (a_{1}x_{11}) ^2 + 2(a_{1}x_{11}) (a_{2} x_{22}) $$

My question is: Were the previous steps correct? How can I have $x_{11}$ alone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\sqrt{p^2} = p$ or $-p$. Also, if you have a variable in one place never expand brackets to have it in more than one place.

Comment: Your algebra looks OK. Now you have something like $ax^2 + bx +c = d$ with $x$ your unknown. Subtract $d$ from both sides and use the quadratic formula. When you're done, check to see that squaring hasn't introduced extra roots and decide which of the two roots of the quadratic makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but how can I deal with it if I did not expand brackets ? any advice

Comment: Thank very much you Ethan Bolker  for your comment and advice. I will work based on that